# Can not install burp certificate on nox

Tags: android, android-emulator, burp, nox

I am trying to install burp certificate on nox emulator. I searched a lot but I did not find solution.

first I got my ip address which is 192.168.1.4 and set burp to listen in all intertfaces.
then I modified nox wifi to proxy over my burp.
then I started to receive requests successfully to my burp but when I try ti visit any https website:
this message is shown:

[image]

I tried to go to http://burp and download the cert.
then change it name to burp.cer
then I went to setting > security > install from SD card and I choose burp cert
but still the security warning appears.

Comment: As Nox bases on Android 9 you need to install the certificates via command-line and root permissions. See second half "Newer rooted devices" of this answer how to install a root CA certificate: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/231025/lets-encrypt-is-there-a-workaround-for-the-2021-ssl-cutoff-for-pre-7-1-1-and/232051#232051

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a problem with the cert which is not installed properly.
Try der as the `cert` extension rather than `cer` and installed it as `Root CA`.

You may also check if you're behind a proxy.